# jquery offset().top returns 0 when I have set an absolute position div "top" to 700px

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu bar I want to display at certain position 
of the page, no matter what size of the browser is 
and as window resize, its position will update

the menu will stay fixed when page scrolls to a certain point

this is what I have done:

*** The problem occurs when window is resized, my nav's offsetTop was updated
but it returns 0, I have no idea why, maybe offset() can not be called twice ??**

Thanks !!!!!

html:

```
<div id="nav">

                <ul id="nav_list">
                    <li>
                    ABOUT
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    WORK
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    CONTACT
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    BLOG
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

css:

```
#nav{
position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    background:#0C6;
    display:block;
    z-index:104;
}

#nav_list{
    margin:auto;
    padding:0;
    width:380px;
    font-family:FoundryJournal-Book;
    font-size:25px;
    color:#C36;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav_list li{
    margin-right:10px;
    display:inline;
}
```

jquery:

```
var scrollTop;
var nav_offsetTop;
var window_height=$(window).height();
var window_height_resize;

// set the nav position !
if(parseInt(window_height)>=700){
        $("#nav").css({top:parseInt(window_height)-5});
        nav_offsetTop=$("#nav").offset().top;
    }


// when window resize

// declare resize delay function
    var resize_delay = (function () {
    var timers = {};
    return function (callback, ms, uniqueId) {
    if (!uniqueId) {
      uniqueId = "Don't call this twice";
    }
    if (timers[uniqueId]) {
      clearTimeout (timers[uniqueId]);
    }
    timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
    })();

$(window).resize(function(){
        resize_delay(function(){
            window_height_resize=$(window).height();
            /* all things needed updated after window resizing */

            // nav re-position
            if(window_height_resize>=780){
               $("#nav").fadeOut(200,function(){
                            // update nav's position
                $(this).css({top:parseInt(window_height_resize)-5});

                            // update nav_offsetTop after resizing
                nav_offsetTop=$(this).offset().top;
                alert(nav_offsetTop)  // return 0 ?!!!!
                $(this).fadeIn(250);
               });
            }
        },20,"window_resize");
 });


//scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
        scrollTop=$(this).scrollTop();

        // nav stay fixed
        if(scrollTop>=nav_offsetTop){
            $("#nav").css({position:"fixed",top:"0px"});
        }else{
            $("#nav").css({position:"absolute",top:nav_offsetTop});
        }
 });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U2hX3/1/

Comment: Your code is incomplete. This is the basic fiddle, after fixing several syntax errors. What's the definition of `resize_delay`? http://jsfiddle.net/U2hX3/

Comment: hey man thanks heaps, I just edited the post, it's in now !!

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? I don't understand the behavior you want.

Comment: nav will stay at the bottom of the page, no matter what size of user's browser is, or when user resize the browser... 

as user scrolls down the page ...when nav reaches the top the of the window, which means (window).scrollTop >= nav.css("top")...the menu bar's position will change to 'fixed' so it'd stay on top of the page 
_______
does this make sense : s